# Combing shipping_options and shipping tabs on onepage magento checkout

Tags: magento

We are currently trying to combine the shipping methods and shipping address details into one tab on the magento checkout. We want to be able to have 3 boxes that are for the different delivery options, that when expanded show the address details required. Does anyone know how this can be done.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/